# Redirect_to in Rails controller doesn't work, but server log shows page as rendered

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an application (RoR 3.1) where a user can change the position of a google maps marker of a business (handled with "business controller"). After he clicks on the "Save new position" button the user should be redirected to the business#show page. But he isn't although the server log shows that business#show is rendered. The position is saved correctly in the database anyhow but I'm remaining on the business#updatemap page.

Here is the code of the view where the user can change the map position:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false&region=IN"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @business.latitude %>, <%= @business.longitude %>);

    var options = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        draggable:true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(
        marker,
        'drag',
        function() {
            document.getElementById('business_latitude').value = marker.position.lat();
            document.getElementById('business_longitude').value = marker.position.lng();
        });
  }
</script>

<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
</div>

<%= form_for :business, :url => { :action => "updatemap" }, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :latitude %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :longitude %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is the relevant part of the business controller:

```
 def updatemap
    @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    if @business.update_attributes(params[:business])
      redirect_to @business, :flash => { :success => "The business was 
                                                      successfully updated!" }
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

And this is the server log:

```
Started GET "/businesses/173-New-Delhi-wrewerwer" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-06 13:22:58 +0100
  Processing by BusinessesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"173-New-Delhi-wrewerwer"}
  Business Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `businesses`.* FROM `businesses` WHERE `businesses`.`id` = 173 ORDER BY businesses.business_name ASC LIMIT 1
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  State Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `states`.* FROM `states` WHERE `states`.`id` = 10 ORDER BY states.name ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `images` WHERE `images`.`business_id` = 173
  Image Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` WHERE `images`.`business_id` = 173
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Rendered businesses/show.html.haml within layouts/application (49.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.haml (3.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.haml (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 155ms (Views: 61.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.1ms)
```

So it says that business/show.html.haml was rendered, but I'm still on the page where I can change the position of the map.

Has anyone an idea of what is going on here? I guess this is a really simple issue but since I'm quite new to coding any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `:remote => true` from your `form` in order to make redirection works.

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was a fast one :-)